# Difference fields are displyed before and after creation

Tags: custom-button, leads, visualforce

In lead object , when I click new to create a new record it calls a vf page (handled by custom button by calling a vf page in 'New ' button). At the time of creation , in one section it is showing 10 fields. But after clicking on save , in that section it is only displaying 5 fields. When I checked in layout , it only displays 5 fields. My question is , how the extra fields gets added at the time of creation.

Please provide a solution and thanks in advance !!!

Comment: this is a custom page? (Create page)

Comment: No its normal lead creation page. Rest of the fields are displayed as per the layout.

Comment: can you check the url I am sure it is apex page as Tushar said.

Comment: do you have two different record type for lead?

Answer (score 0):

Your `New` page is actually a Visualforce page. So all fields are controlled by that page. After saving a new record the user is redirected to the standard page *layout*. Over there the fields are controlled by *layout*.

There are two different things:

- visualforce page - 10 fields
- page layout - 5 fields

If you want to edit the `New` page fields -  edit your visualforce page.
Otherwise edit the page layout.